# NullReferenceException adding to a dictionary - very certain that nothing is null

Tags: c#, dictionary

Where `Sessions` is a `Dictionary<Guid, WebSession>`, and `NewSession` is `new WebSession()` I have this line:

```
Sessions.Add(NewSession.SessionID, NewSession);
```

Now at this point you're probably rolling your eyeballs and thinking "well either Sessions is null, or NewSession.SessionID is null." However:

```
Sessions == null
false
NewSession.SessionID == null
false
NewSession == null
false
```

It's pretty intermittent. Happens maybe one time in 50. And whenever it happens, I can just do `Sessions.Add(NewSession.SessionID, NewSession);` in the immediate window and it works fine.

The constructor for `WebSession` is synchronous, and `Sessions` is a vanilla dictionary with no added sugar.

I'm pretty sure I've done due diligence at this point. It's a harmless enough thing to happen in my application and it's trapped and handled cleanly - but I'm stumped as to what causes it in the first place.

Edit: I'm wondering if it's because my `WebSession` inherits `: Dictionary<String, Object>` but its constructor doesn't call `base()` - that still wouldn't explain it though since I can check that the object isn't null before doing `Add(..)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)

Comment: what about showing a stack-trace? usually this unveils everything ...

Comment: Add some asserts with messages so that the message tells you what exactly was null.

Comment: The stack trace shows nothing useful except it going inside `Sessions.Add` and `Sessions.Insert` - the Insert is where the NRE occurs.

Comment: @usr - it's in .net framework code that the exception is happening, not mine. I can check beforehand that nothing is null and it's fine.

Comment: Oh ok then it is a threading bug. A Dictionary does not have bugs. Neither does a Guid. It is a threading problem which causes some internal stuff to be null at unexpected times.

Comment: @usr exactly my thought :) ... the thing "happens 1 out of 50" makes it very suspicious ...

Comment: Actually, if you had posted the stack trace this would have been easy to prove right away.

Comment: I'll try and grab an actual strace, may take a while being a 1-in-50 thing though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use a thread-safe collection such as [ConcurrentDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx), or implement your own sychronization.

Attempting to access a `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` from multiple threads can result in heisenbugs, which may well manifest themselves as a `NullReferenceException`.